# GNU Makefile "preprocessor"?

Tags: makefile, preprocessor, gnu-make, analyzer

Is there an option to output the "preprocessed" makefile, something equivalent to the GCC's `-E` option?

I have a project comprised of an hierarchy of dozens of modules, each with its makefile. The build is invoked from a master makefile. That master makefile contains includes, variable definitions, command line option dependent variables, etc.

So, essentially, I am looking for the processed makefile, including all substitutions.

Comment: Isn't `make -n` useful in this context?

Comment: @EugeniuRosca - looks like this option does not create the result I am looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Not that I'm aware of. The closest thing you can get to this is the output from `make -qp` (or similar) which will dump the make database out at you.

Part of the problem with this request is that many of the substitutions/etc. happen as targets are processed and the list of targets isn't necessarily known without actually attempting a build (at least to an extent) so it isn't necessarily possible to fully expand/etc. a makefile in-place.

The `make -d` output is also useful for certain incidental information related to how make has processed the makefiles but doesn't contain makefile contents directly.

[Remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) might also be able to provide some extra useful information.

If you are looking for the computed value of some assembled/etc. global make variable then [this](http://blog.melski.net/2010/11/30/makefile-hacks-print-the-value-of-any-variable/) blog post by Eric Melski is likely to be very helpful.

tl;dr It adds a target like this to the Makefile (though there's more magic in the blog post so I suggest reading it).

> ```
> print-%:
>     @echo '$*=$($*)'
>     @echo '  origin = $(origin $*)'
>     @echo '  flavor = $(flavor $*)'
>     @echo '   value = $(value  $*)'
> ```

Though in personal use I replaced that first line with something more like this

```
@echo '$*=$(subst ','\'',$($*))'
```

to keep the quoting of the result correct.

Comment: Thanks. There was a lot of information (moer than 3,000 lines of output), and it requires some digging-into, but I guess that with enough time spent on it, one can figure out the required information.

Comment: @ysap What, specifically, are you trying to find out? There may be simpler ways to do it. (Actually, I'll add one often useful method I just remembered to the answer now.)

Comment: Basically, to reverse engineer a project, in order to create an IDE (Eclipse) based project. There are many modules, making a couple of libraries, and many are not compiled/linked into the final binary. There are module selection variables (switches) in one of the common makefile modules.