# Makefile: replace macro with final value: for understanding the makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have a huge makefile with a lot of macro substitutions. Would it be possible to process the makefile to output a version that substitutes the macros with the final version of the Makefile? This is to improve readability, so that I can understand it better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List goals/targets in GNU make that contain variables in their definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063507/list-goals-targets-in-gnu-make-that-contain-variables-in-their-definition)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121698/gnu-makefile-preprocessor